# Using an array to call tones using stdlib java library

Tags: java, eclipse

Using the following library:

https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/

I am trying to Play a tone in java for .4 seconds from a file using Stdin.fromFile using an array. I can write the code and make it play using `playTone (double, double)` the code is as follows:

```
package csc402;
import stdlib.StdAudio;
import stdlib.StdIn;

public class PlaySong {

    public static void playTone(double frequency, double duration) {

        double[] values = StdIn.readAllDoubles();
        final int sliceCount = (int) (StdAudio.SAMPLE_RATE * duration);
        final double[] slices = new double[sliceCount+1];
        for (int i = 0; i <= sliceCount; i++) {
            slices[i] = Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i * frequency / StdAudio.SAMPLE_RATE);
        }
        StdAudio.play(slices);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StdIn.fromFile("data/a2song.txt");
        playTone (0,.4);
        StdAudio.close();
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

My `a2song.txt` file is as follows

```
278.4375
278.4375
417.1849
417.1849
468.2742
468.2742
417.1849
```

My question is what am I missing ? The code runs fine but isn't playing the tone.

Comment: That's nice, but do you have a question?

Comment: What is `stdlib`? That isn't part of standard Java so we don't know anything about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example from the `stdlib` doc to play one tone:
(you probably have seen it already as your code looks like it)

https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/15inout/Tone.java.html

```
public class Tone {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double hz       = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);    // frequency in Hz
        double duration = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);    // duration in seconds

        int n = (int) (StdAudio.SAMPLE_RATE * duration);

        // build sine wave with desired frequency
        double[] a = new double[n+1];
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            a[i] = Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i * hz / StdAudio.SAMPLE_RATE);
        }

        // play using standard audio
        StdAudio.play(a);
    }
}
```

That plays one tone, and each value in your file is one tone, so you need to call a similar method for each value of your file.

That works for me: (I did not use the `StdIn.fromFile` as it does not compile, I hardcoded the values in the array instead)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //StdIn.fromFile("data/a2song.txt");
    double[] values = new double[] {278.4375, 278.4375, 417.1849, 417.1849, 468.2742, 468.2742, 417.1849};
    for(double value : values) {
        playTone (value,.4);
    }
    StdAudio.close();
    System.exit(0);
}

public static void playTone(double frequency, double duration) {
    int n = (int) (StdAudio.SAMPLE_RATE * duration);
    // build sine wave with desired frequency
    double[] a = new double[n+1];
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        a[i] = Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i * frequency / StdAudio.SAMPLE_RATE);
    }
    // play using standard audio
    StdAudio.play(a);
}
```

Comment: I like this way much better. I know how to do it the way you should above. I also have done it calling on each tone use playTone (248.75, .4).

Comment: The requirement was to use the StdIn.fromFile, that is whats stopping me from completing it because, I dont know how to call on that. Essentially I dont know how to call that file to play/use whats in my a2song.txt file. (essentially the HZ for Twinkle twinkle litter star).

Comment: I don't think there is a `StdIn.fromFile` can't find it in the API doc. StdIn reads from standard input. There is however a `In.readDoubles` method that you might be able to use to read the file.

Comment: Ok. I am working on a project for one of my masters classes. Thats what he asked us to do. I found it a little odd as well. I sent him an email last night. Will wait for his reponse. thanks for your help.

Comment: @JosephYeagle it could also be that he wants the program to be run by command line and then you can feed it the values manually. Anyway the tone playing issue is sorted.